# How to check for duplicate keys and delete previous value from Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` which contains values with keys. According to my condition, I will have duplicate keys which are strictly not permitted in `Dictionary`. Now my question is: how to check for the previous duplicate key in the current `Dictionary` and delete it to add the new?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **ContainsKey()** method of the Dictionary to find out whether Dictionary already contains your key or not

```
dict.ContainsKey(Key)
```

it **returns** a **true** if the Dictionary contains key otherwise returns a **false**

you **don't need to delete** the key you can just overwrite the value

```
 if(dict.ContainsKey(Key))
    {
          dict[key]=YOUR_NEW_VALUE;
    }
    else
    {
          dict.Add ( key,YOUR_NEW_VALUE);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

My advice would be to think of deleting as simply overwriting the `Value` member of the matching entry.

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("key"))
{
    myDictionary["key"] = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `ContainsKey()`:

```
if(dict.ContainsKey(YourKey))
    dict[YourKey] = YourNewValue;
```

where `dict` is your dictionary.

This line overwrites the new value to the key:

```
dict[YourKey] = YourNewValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ContainsKey method to find existing key like this:

```
 if (yourdictc.ContainsKey("YourKey"))
   { 
     //Do Somethig
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var uniqueValues = myDict.GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
                         .Select(group => group.First())
                         .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an add-or-update behaviour you don't need to call ContainsKey. Just assign the value and it will be updated if the key exists. If not, it will be added.

```
dict[key] = newValue;
```